# WPF and local database, which one to choose?

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I am working on WPF application, and now I have to choose which database to use. It will be local database.

I am thinking about SQLite, but I am not sure. I am not sure how much data my database will contain, maybe a lot, it depends on users use of application. In that case maybe SQLite is not good solution.

Maybe it is best solution to get use Microsoft SQL Server Express.

Comment: If the software is for end-users then choose one that doesn't need to be installed

Comment: SQLite can handle a lot of data. Where it falls down is concurrent access. If you are going to have more than one thread/process/user/whatever try to access the db at the same time, you'll run into issues. They aren't insurmountable issues, but you will need to deal with them.

Comment: No, there will be no concurrent access. It is local program.

Comment: I think PostgreSQL is popular as an embedded db too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would choose the MSSQL Express Edition because its the most well intergrated with .Net. And if you need to upgrade to Standard Edition its fully compatible you just upgrade it without change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with open source databases to cut down the cost MySQL is the ideal solution. it's competent to the MSSQL Server and one of the top most open source databases.